# Rails i18n method results in segmentation fault?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, rails-i18n, string-interpolation

I have a class called "StoryPresenter" which acts as a wrapper around my model object (an instance of class called "Story") and helps present the model's data to my views.  An instance of StoryPresenter contains an instance of a story, as well as the following method:

```
def state
  if story.school_state_territory.blank?
    ""
  else
    " | #{ story.school_state_territory }"
  end
end
```

The above method works fine, however my Rails server crashes when I add the Rails i18n method and refresh my browser:

```
def state
  if story.school_state_territory.blank?
    ""
  else
    " | #{ t(story.school_state_territory) }"
  end
end
```

After a crash, when I restart the server and refresh the browser **with the i18n method still in place**, the page loads but I see HTML visible on the page which indicates the translation key for the given attribute is missing from the en.yml file.  A warning or something similar would be expected (since the key is in fact missing), but what I wouldn't expect in this scenario is for the Rails server to crash.

I see the following output in the server logs after the crash occurs:

```
Started GET "/stories/drafts" for ::1 at 2016-06-28 10:48:42 -0400
Processing by StoriesController#drafts as HTML
(eval):1: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000105353028
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Some relevant information from the crash report:

```
Process:               ruby [4432]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/ruby
Identifier:            ruby
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [2433]
Responsible:           Terminal [280]
User ID:               501
Crashed Thread:        2  server.rb:285
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000105353028
VM Regions Near 0x105353028:
MALLOC_LARGE           000000010529c000-0000000105353000 [  732K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> VM_ALLOCATE            0000000105353000-0000000105354000 [    4K] rw-/rwx SM=ALI  
MALLOC_LARGE           00000001053a4000-0000000105698000 [ 3024K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Thread 2 Crashed:: server.rb:285
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9184bf06 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889bd4ec pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91f736e7 abort + 129
3   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001040152f9 die + 9
4   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010401553e rb_bug_context + 574
5   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001040eb773 sigsegv + 83 (signal.c:805)
6   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff894eb52a _sigtramp + 26
```

I see the "Kern_Invalid_Address" exception code, is that relevant to the cause of the crash?

Gemfile.lock here:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.6)
      actionpack (= 4.2.6)
      actionview (= 4.2.6)
      activejob (= 4.2.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.6)
      actionview (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.6)
      activemodel (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.6)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.4.0)
    arel (6.0.3)
    ast (2.3.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bower-rails (0.10.0)
    brakeman (3.3.2)
    builder (3.2.2)
    bullet (5.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      uniform_notifier (~> 1.10.0)
    bundler-audit (0.5.0)
      bundler (~> 1.2)
      thor (~> 0.18)
    byebug (9.0.5)
    capybara (2.7.1)
      addressable
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    cliver (0.3.2)
    coderay (1.1.1)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
    database_cleaner (1.5.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    em-websocket (0.5.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.2.0.1)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    factory_girl (4.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.7.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.7.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    ffi (1.9.10)
    font-awesome-sass (4.6.2)
      sass (>= 3.2)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    guard (2.14.0)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-livereload (2.5.2)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      guard (~> 2.8)
      guard-compat (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.8)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.1.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    lol_dba (2.0.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.10)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.9.0)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    mysql2 (0.4.4)
    nenv (0.3.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.8)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
      pkg-config (~> 1.1.7)
    notiffany (0.1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    parser (2.3.1.2)
      ast (~> 2.2)
    pkg-config (1.1.7)
    poltergeist (1.9.0)
      capybara (~> 2.1)
      cliver (~> 0.3.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.2.0)
    powerpack (0.1.1)
    pry (0.10.3)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.6)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.6)
      actionpack (= 4.2.6)
      actionview (= 4.2.6)
      activejob (= 4.2.6)
      activemodel (= 4.2.6)
      activerecord (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.6)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.6)
      actionpack (= 4.2.6)
      activesupport (= 4.2.6)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rainbow (2.1.0)
    rake (11.2.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
    rb-inotify (0.9.7)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (4.2.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec-core (3.4.4)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.4.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-support (3.4.1)
    rubocop (0.40.0)
      parser (>= 2.3.1.0, < 3.0)
      powerpack (~> 0.1)
      rainbow (>= 1.99.1, < 3.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    ruby-progressbar (1.8.1)
    ruby_dep (1.3.1)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    shoulda-matchers (3.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
    simple_form (3.2.1)
      actionpack (> 4, < 5.1)
      activemodel (> 4, < 5.1)
    slop (3.6.0)
    sprockets (3.6.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    teaspoon (1.1.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.5, < 6)
    teaspoon-mocha (2.3.3)
      teaspoon (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unicode-display_width (1.0.5)
    uniform_notifier (1.10.0)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    websocket-driver (0.6.4)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bower-rails (~> 0.10.0)
  brakeman
  bullet (~> 5.1)
  bundler-audit
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  database_cleaner
  factory_girl_rails
  font-awesome-sass (~> 4.6.2)
  guard-livereload (~> 2.5)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  lol_dba
  mysql2 (>= 0.3.13, < 0.5)
  poltergeist
  rails (= 4.2.6)
  rspec-rails (~> 3.4)
  rubocop
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  shoulda-matchers (~> 3.1)
  simple_form
  teaspoon-mocha
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.12.5
```

**UPDATE 1:**

All thread traces below:

```
Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9184c07a __select + 10
1   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104188439 rb_thread_fd_select + 1625 (.thread_pthread.c:1090)
2   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010405ad84 select_call + 1188 (io.c:8435)
3   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010401f289 rb_ensure + 169 (eval.c:901)
4   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104050a5c rb_f_select + 140 (io.c:8853)
5   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001041736fa vm_call_cfunc + 314 (.vm_insnhelper.c:1638)
6   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010415c4c0 vm_exec_core + 11952 (insns.def:995)
7   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416dd4c vm_exec + 124 (vm.c:1650)
8   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104169237 rb_yield + 183 (.vm_eval.c:1028)
9   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010407738e rb_obj_tap + 14 (object.c:693)
10  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001041736fa vm_call_cfunc + 314 (.vm_insnhelper.c:1638)
11  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010415c264 vm_exec_core + 11348 (insns.def:964)
12  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416dd4c vm_exec + 124 (vm.c:1650)
13  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104021ff0 rb_load_internal0 + 288 (load.c:619)
14  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001040228a5 rb_require_internal + 1813 (load.c:998)
15  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104022078 rb_f_require + 24 (load.c:1045)
16  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001041736fa vm_call_cfunc + 314 (.vm_insnhelper.c:1638)
17  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010415c4c0 vm_exec_core + 11952 (insns.def:995)
18  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416dd4c vm_exec + 124 (vm.c:1650)
19  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010401e2b8 ruby_exec_internal + 152 (eval.c:250)
20  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010401e1c6 ruby_run_node + 54 (eval.c:302)
21  ruby                            0x0000000103fc8f2f main + 79 (main.c:36)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff865675ad start + 1

Thread 1:: ruby-timer-thr
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9184d2a2 poll + 10
1   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418c823 thread_timer + 371 (.thread_pthread.c:1458)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba99d _pthread_body + 131
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba91a _pthread_start + 168
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889b8351 thread_start + 13

Thread 2 Crashed:: server.rb:285
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9184bf06 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889bd4ec pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91f736e7 abort + 129
3   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001040152f9 die + 9
4   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010401553e rb_bug_context + 574
5   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001040eb773 sigsegv + 83 (signal.c:805)
6   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff894eb52a _sigtramp + 26

Thread 3:: utils.rb:156
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9184bdb6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889bb728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001041850a8 native_sleep + 424 (.thread_pthread.c:342)
3   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001041856dd rb_thread_sleep_deadly + 173 (thread.c:1062)
4   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418e909 queue_sleep + 9 (.thread_sync.c:767)
5   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010401f289 rb_ensure + 169 (eval.c:901)
6   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418e6fd queue_do_pop + 173 (ruby.h:2041)
7   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001041736fa vm_call_cfunc + 314 (.vm_insnhelper.c:1638)
8   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010415c4c0 vm_exec_core + 11952 (insns.def:995)
9   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416dd4c vm_exec + 124 (vm.c:1650)
10  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416c594 vm_invoke_proc + 196 (vm.c:1046)
11  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418c557 thread_start_func_2 + 1463 (thread.c:584)
12  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418bf7a thread_start_func_1 + 170 (.thread_pthread.c:882)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba99d _pthread_body + 131
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba91a _pthread_start + 168
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889b8351 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: server.rb:285
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9184c07a __select + 10
1   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104188439 rb_thread_fd_select + 1625 (.thread_pthread.c:1090)
2   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104188922 select_single + 34 (thread.c:3778)
3   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010401f289 rb_ensure + 169 (eval.c:901)
4   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418871c rb_wait_for_single_fd + 124 (thread.c:3818)
5   wait.bundle                     0x0000000104665db3 io_wait_readable + 131 (wait.c:64)
6   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001041736fa vm_call_cfunc + 314 (.vm_insnhelper.c:1638)
7   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010415c4c0 vm_exec_core + 11952 (insns.def:995)
8   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416dd4c vm_exec + 124 (vm.c:1650)
9   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416c594 vm_invoke_proc + 196 (vm.c:1046)
10  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418c557 thread_start_func_2 + 1463 (thread.c:584)
11  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418bf7a thread_start_func_1 + 170 (.thread_pthread.c:882)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba99d _pthread_body + 131
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba91a _pthread_start + 168
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889b8351 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: server.rb:285
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9184c07a __select + 10
1   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104188439 rb_thread_fd_select + 1625 (.thread_pthread.c:1090)
2   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104188922 select_single + 34 (thread.c:3778)
3   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010401f289 rb_ensure + 169 (eval.c:901)
4   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418871c rb_wait_for_single_fd + 124 (thread.c:3818)
5   wait.bundle                     0x0000000104665db3 io_wait_readable + 131 (wait.c:64)
6   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001041736fa vm_call_cfunc + 314 (.vm_insnhelper.c:1638)
7   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010415c4c0 vm_exec_core + 11952 (insns.def:995)
8   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416dd4c vm_exec + 124 (vm.c:1650)
9   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416c594 vm_invoke_proc + 196 (vm.c:1046)
10  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418c557 thread_start_func_2 + 1463 (thread.c:584)
11  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418bf7a thread_start_func_1 + 170 (.thread_pthread.c:882)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba99d _pthread_body + 131
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba91a _pthread_start + 168
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889b8351 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: server.rb:285
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9184c07a __select + 10
1   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104188439 rb_thread_fd_select + 1625 (.thread_pthread.c:1090)
2   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104188922 select_single + 34 (thread.c:3778)
3   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010401f289 rb_ensure + 169 (eval.c:901)
4   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418871c rb_wait_for_single_fd + 124 (thread.c:3818)
5   wait.bundle                     0x0000000104665db3 io_wait_readable + 131 (wait.c:64)
6   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001041736fa vm_call_cfunc + 314 (.vm_insnhelper.c:1638)
7   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010415c4c0 vm_exec_core + 11952 (insns.def:995)
8   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416dd4c vm_exec + 124 (vm.c:1650)
9   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416c594 vm_invoke_proc + 196 (vm.c:1046)
10  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418c557 thread_start_func_2 + 1463 (thread.c:584)
11  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418bf7a thread_start_func_1 + 170 (.thread_pthread.c:882)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba99d _pthread_body + 131
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba91a _pthread_start + 168
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889b8351 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: server.rb:285
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9184c07a __select + 10
1   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104188439 rb_thread_fd_select + 1625 (.thread_pthread.c:1090)
2   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104188922 select_single + 34 (thread.c:3778)
3   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010401f289 rb_ensure + 169 (eval.c:901)
4   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418871c rb_wait_for_single_fd + 124 (thread.c:3818)
5   wait.bundle                     0x0000000104665db3 io_wait_readable + 131 (wait.c:64)
6   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001041736fa vm_call_cfunc + 314 (.vm_insnhelper.c:1638)
7   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010415c4c0 vm_exec_core + 11952 (insns.def:995)
8   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416dd4c vm_exec + 124 (vm.c:1650)
9   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416c594 vm_invoke_proc + 196 (vm.c:1046)
10  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418c557 thread_start_func_2 + 1463 (thread.c:584)
11  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418bf7a thread_start_func_1 + 170 (.thread_pthread.c:882)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba99d _pthread_body + 131
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba91a _pthread_start + 168
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889b8351 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: server.rb:285
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9184c07a __select + 10
1   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104188439 rb_thread_fd_select + 1625 (.thread_pthread.c:1090)
2   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x0000000104188922 select_single + 34 (thread.c:3778)
3   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010401f289 rb_ensure + 169 (eval.c:901)
4   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418871c rb_wait_for_single_fd + 124 (thread.c:3818)
5   wait.bundle                     0x0000000104665db3 io_wait_readable + 131 (wait.c:64)
6   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x00000001041736fa vm_call_cfunc + 314 (.vm_insnhelper.c:1638)
7   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010415c4c0 vm_exec_core + 11952 (insns.def:995)
8   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416dd4c vm_exec + 124 (vm.c:1650)
9   libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010416c594 vm_invoke_proc + 196 (vm.c:1046)
10  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418c557 thread_start_func_2 + 1463 (thread.c:584)
11  libruby.2.3.0.dylib             0x000000010418bf7a thread_start_func_1 + 170 (.thread_pthread.c:882)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba99d _pthread_body + 131
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889ba91a _pthread_start + 168
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff889b8351 thread_start + 13

Thread 2 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007feb6491dff8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000001603  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007feb6491e020  rsp: 0x00007feb6491dff8
   r8: 0x0000000000000040   r9: 0x00007fff73c491e0  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007feb6491e150  r13: 0x000000000000000a  r14: 0x0000700000108000  r15: 0x0000000104209072
  rip: 0x00007fff9184bf06  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff73c47008

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

Comment: Thread 2 crashed because it caught the segmentation fault signal... this doesn't necessarily mean that it's the thread that cause the segmentation fault (I know, confusing)... could you paste the C backtrace for the other threads as well?

Comment: P.S. It could be that the `state` function is throwing an exception (i.e., the `t` function crashing), causing a `longjmp` to occur. If not handled properly, this could cause a chain reaction, effecting other stuff. Try adding an `ensure ; ""` line at the end of the function.

Comment: C backtraces added.

Comment: Thinking out loud: Looks like buffer overflow? Thread 3 seems the only other candidate for crash causes, but it seems to have been waiting on a conditional variable (I'm assuming background task handling, such as `activejob`)... this might mean that Thread 2 both cause the exception and caught it, which would be bad for logging, as the signal was caught on a fresh stack (no backtrace)... but, Thread 2 shows `server.rb:285`, maybe it was polling using `select` as well... Did you try the `ensure`?

Comment: Try replacing `" | #{ t(story.school_state_territory) }"` with `" | #{ t(story.school_state_territory)  rescue "" }"` ... I wonder if this helps.

Comment: adding 'rescue "" ' did fix the crash, which solves the immediate problem.  However I also determined I was mistakenly including the helper modules outside the presenter class rather than inside.  I'm interested in knowing why this would cause a server crash, rather than just a Rails error inside the browser.

Comment: I'll try writing something more comprehensive as an answer, as I'll need the space. Which server were you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

A workaround (not a solution for the underlying bug) was found by replacing:

```
" | #{ t(story.school_state_territory) }"
```

With:

```
" | #{ t(story.school_state_territory) rescue "" }"
```

It seems an unhandled exception from `t` caused a chain reaction that led to a crash.

Ruby implementing exceptions in C using `longjmp` which means the code execution chain stops and never returns to it's original position.

When implementing a server, the chain of execution is usually looped in what is known as an "event loop" or the reactor pattern.

If a `longjmp` breaks out of this loop, the server might (and probably will) crash or hang.

This is similar to how Ruby code, when not handling any exceptions, will jump back up to the top of the stack and potentially kill the process (return).

For this reason, when implementing a Ruby callback from C, it's usually important to protect the callback from any `longjmp` or Ruby exceptions. Ruby MRI provides C API for this (i.e. `rb_protect`).

The same applies for FFI. When using FFI, it is important to "wrap" callbacks in rescue statements before passing them to FFI functions that take callbacks.

It would be beneficial to find the callback handler (be it the server calling Ruby to handle a request, or another library such as a background task library) and submit a bug report.

Comment: Not being familiar with the underlying C implementation of Ruby, how would I go about finding the callback handler you refer to?

Comment: @toomanyrichies , I would look back into the Ruby code and see were the call to `state` originated (maybe, for testing, print `state` backtraces)... the call  at some point backtraces to the "first" function in "ruby land" this could also be a call to a `block` not just a function. If you didn't write anything special, it should either be a server response block/callback (an HTTP request is passed to the callback, usually as a Rack `env` variable) or a scheduled task (the task itself is the callback and it is being called by the scheduler).